# Python how to check if word is in list and in input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, words

I'm trying to get my program to go through an input sentence (e.g. "hello there!")
and see if any of the words in the input are in a list.
here is the code so far:

```
def findWholeWord(w):
    return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search
i.upper() #i is the inputted variable as a string
WordsDocument = open('WordsDocument.txt').readlines()
for words in WordsDocument:
    WordsList.append(words)
for word in i:
    if findWholeWord(word) in WordsList:
        print("Word Match")
```

Can someone help me develop a better solution / fix this so it works?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def findWholeWord(w):               # input string w

    match_list = []                 # list containing matched words
    input_list = w.split(" ")

    file = open('WordsDocument.txt', 'r')
    text = file.read().lower()
    file.close()
    text = re.sub('[^a-z\ \']+', " ", text)
    words_list = list(text.split()) 

    for word in input_list:
        if word in words_list:
            print("Word Found: " + str(word))
            match_list.append(word)
    return match_list
```